# Adding multiple objects to svg and adding drag behaviour issue

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am totally new to SVG and d3 library. I need to add dynamically add 5 circle to svg which all contains draggable event handler. I have written code for adding a single circle and adding draggable behaviour to the same and its working fine. Now I am trying the same thing inside for loop in order to add 5 circle. It displays all circle but when I drag a particular circle and put it some where then it stays there and again when i touch another circle old circle get vanished from the position where we placed and appears on new circle where we started next. Please have a look at below mentioned code. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

```
   function addCircles()
    {    
    var box = d3.select(".box");  

         for(var i = 0;i<5;i++)
         {

            var drag = d3.behavior.drag()  
                 .on('dragstart', function() { console.log("dragstart"); circle.style('fill', 'red'); })
                 .on('drag', function() { console.log("drag X - " + d3.event.x + " Y - " + d3.event.y); circle.attr('cx', d3.event.x)
                                                .attr('cy', d3.event.y); })
                 .on('dragend', function() {    console.log("dragend - " + d3.event.x); 
                                                circle.style('fill', 'green');  }); 

var circle = box.selectAll('.draggableCircle'+i)  
                    .data([{ x: i*15, y: i*15, r: 10 }])
                    .enter()
                    .append('svg:circle')
                    .attr('class', 'draggableCircle'+i)
                    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
                    .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; })
                    .call(drag)
                    .style('fill', 'green');


         } 
    }
```

I have checked out after debugging code in chrome and found out that position of dragEnd is not being detected.

Comment: You fancy putting a JSFiddle together so we can play with the code ?

Comment: didn't get your question. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: put your code here : https://jsfiddle.net/ that way we can edit, save, and show you working example, if possible. Just make sure you reference D3 in the left column, html javascript and css in seperate windows, press save, copy the URL here and we will have a look :)

Comment: Please check out following link and try dragging each and every circle in green one by one. https://jsfiddle.net/ta2ek6zj/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle didnt work so I had to make my own from the code provided : http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/6932/

Create the data first then draw circles from that data, rather than doing it all at once.

```
var nodeData = [];

     for(var i = 1;i<15;i++) //change the value 15 to however many circles you want
     {      

        nodeData.push({
           x:i*15,
           y:i*15,
           r:10
        })    

     }
```

Then use this data to create circles :

```
 var circle = box.selectAll('.draggableCircle'+i)  
                    //.data([{ x: i*15, y: i*15, r: 10 }])
                    .data(nodeData)
                    .enter()
                    .append('svg:circle')
                    .attr('class', function(d,i){
                    return 'draggableCircle'+i; //changed this to use i in the loop 
                                              //through the nodes not i in the for loop
                    })
                    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
                    .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; })
                    .style('fill', 'green')
                    .call(drag)
```

Also your drag wasn't done correctly. You had this line :

```
circle.attr('cx', d3.event.x).attr('cy', d3.event.y);
```

You dont want this as your going through each circle and calling the drag on all of them. You only want to call it on the element you're 'dragging' like so :

```
function dragmove(d, i) //-updates the co-ordinates 
{
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy; 


    d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d,i)
    {
        return "translate(" + [ d.x,d.y ] + ")";
    });    
}
```

I think that was all the changes I made to make it work.

On a side note, with JSFiddle, you have to include the D3 library on the left hand side, other wise it wont work. Also, when calling your '`drawCircles()`' function in the html, you have to change the loading of the fiddle otherwise it wont be able to find the function. Also, with all this said, if you were to use JSFiddle again in a question, please make sure it works before sending SO users a link.

```
EDIT
```

I added this line to get the correct circle positions on load :

```
circle.attr("transform", function(d){
          return "translate(" + [ d.x,d.y ] + ")";
          })
```

Now the drag works perfectly :)) Hope this helps

Comment: Notice in the fiddle provided, when you start the drag, the node jumps, I'll work on that now to fix the problem

Comment: I gone through that particular link and noticed that when we are trying to drag circle automatically position changes and get places downwards. .can you please check it out and do needful help